# Flutter (android studio & vscode) automatically stuck after few days in windows

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When I install flutter, android studio & vscode it works well for 2~3 days.
But after 2~3 days I face problems while I want to use it.

#### Problems something like this:

- Android studio don't start
- Android studio stuck
- Visual studio code starts but when I use command `flutter run` or `flutter pub get` it stuck on it.
- While open VSCode it shows "Analyzing" and stuck on it
- When I use `ctrl+click` on any functions or methods it doesn't navigate me on that function
- Sometimes android studio but don't work when I try to close the window it doesn't work.

---

#### My system configurations:

- Windows 10
- flutter latest version
- dart latest version
- vs code latest version
- android studio latest version
- ram 32 GB
- processor more then 2 GHz (intel, I don't know exact model name)

---

### **Note:** I reinstalled Windows 10 OS completely but It also doesn't work.

Exactly how can I know what error is and how?
How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

maybe your hard disk is full , try to clean it , and reinstall vscode again

Comment: I have lot of free space about 130 GB +

Comment: try to reinstall vscode

Comment: But What about android studio